# Benefiting from a non-Jew's labor on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shabbat, amira-leakum

I understand that if a non-Jew performs labor on Shabbes for a Jew, the Jew cannot benefit from that labor - but what if it was performed for a group of people, only one/some of whom are Jewish? For the sake of an example, let's say that a non-Jew turns on a heater because a group of people has just walked in from the rain, but one of those people is Jewish.

Please, only sourced answers. I would like to see halakhic discussion on this issue, which I can then check in printed literature.

Comment: It is permissible anyway to ask a non-Jew to turn on heating on Shabbos because *ha'kol cholim etzel ha'tzinah*.

Comment: Just a comment because I don't have sources handy, but even more extreme than heating (which is a general "can't do for one without everyone"), even more specific stuff - e.g., I heard once in a Shiur from my Rabbi, and then got confirmation from a Rabbi who travels a lot and did this himself, that if you are in a non-Jewish hotel (not run by Jews, majority of guests not Jewish) and there is food available prepared on Shabbos then if there is no Kashrus problem (e.g., classic example according to most is ordinary coffee)  then you can eat/drink with no concern. As opposed to a Jewish hotel

Comment: where it becomes a **big** concern that everything be prepared in advance, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, a Jew is permitted to benefit from the *melacha* (forbidden Shabbat labor) a non-Jew does for himself or for other non-Jews.

R Daniel Braude ([Learn Shabbos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1988022304), pp. 521ff) writes that

> - **a Jew can benefit from a *melacha* performed by a non-Jew for himself** (if there is no need for more *melacha* to benefit the Jew),
>   e.g., switching a light is fine as the non-Jew doesn't need more work
>   to benefit the Jew, boiling water is not as there needs to be more
>   water for the Jew
> - a Jew can benefit from a *melacha* performed a non-Jew **if the non-Jew doesn't know the Jew and the Jew is not visibly present** at the
>   time of the *melacha*
> - if it is unclear for whom the non-Jew did the *melacha*, it depends on who is present. If it is a majority of Jews, it is forbidden to
>   benefit, **if the majority are non-Jews, it is permitted**
> - **if it is clear the non-Jew performed the *melacha* for non-Jews**, then Jews can benefit even if they are the majority

In your specific case, it appears permitted since the Jew is a minority in a group of non-Jews for which the *melacha* was performed.

These laws are discussed in [Shulchan Aruch OC 325](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.325.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), see there with Mishna Brura. See esp. [325:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.325.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as well as [OC 276:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.276.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and commentaries. In English see [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Amirah_LeNochri) and [here](https://outorah.org/p/49393/).

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).